# Node.js: Processing a stream without running out of memory

Tags: node.js, stream, file-processing

I'm trying to read a giant logfile (250,000 lines), parsing each line into a JSON object, and insert each JSON object to CouchDB for analytics.

I'm trying to do this by creating a buffered stream that will process each chunk seperately, but I always run out of memory after about 300 lines. It seems like using [buffered streams](https://github.com/dodo/node-bufferstream) and [util.pump](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_pump_readablestream_writablestream_callback) should avoid this, but apparently not.

(Perhaps there are better tools for this than node.js and CouchDB, but I'm interested in learning how to do this kind of file processing in node.js and think it should be possible.)

CoffeeScript below, JavaScript here: https://gist.github.com/5a89d3590f0a9ca62a23

```
fs = require 'fs'
util = require('util')
BufferStream = require('bufferstream')

files = [
  "logfile1",
]

files.forEach (file)->
  stream = new BufferStream({encoding:'utf8', size:'flexible'})
  stream.split("\n")
  stream.on("split", (chunk, token)->
    line = chunk.toString()
    # parse line into JSON and insert in database
  )
  util.pump(fs.createReadStream(file, {encoding: 'utf8'}), stream)
```

Comment: You should be able to use a stream to feed the file to you. On 'data' events you can pause the stream then split each chunk on "\n". Keep the last item in the split for the next chunk if it doesn't end in a "\n". Make sure to process the remainder when the "end" event is fired. Using bufferstream will run you out of memory, your essentially moving the file in to an array of buffers in memory. Also stream.pipe() should be used instead of util.pump().

Comment: I would recommend using fs.createReadStream() - http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: Maybe this could help:
[https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:
[Memory leak when using streams in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550180/memory-leak-when-using-streams-in-node-js)

Try to use `pipe()` to solve it.