# Memory leak when using streams in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Supposed I have a simple http server such as:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Got some data: ' + data);
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('Request ended!');
  });

  res.end('Hello world!');
}).listen(3000);
```

So, basically the default 101 sample, nothing special so far - except that I subscribe to the `data` and the `end` event of the readable `req` stream. Now I wonder whether I have to unsubscribe those events when I no longer need them?

Or are they cleared automatically when the readable stream ends?

Could code like this cause a memory leak?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326300/garbage-collection-with-node-js) might be helpful.

Comment: That was actually helpful in a more common sense. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(This answer contains links to the revelant parts of the node.js source code)

Before answering your question, let's talk about events. When you do this:

```
emitter.on('an-event', listener);
```

`listener` gets added to a [list](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21/lib/events.js#L35) attached to `emitter`. Later, when `emitter` triggers the event, it notifies all the listeners subscribed to the event by iterating through the list. The magic of node.js event emitters is that you don't declare or manage that list yourself.

However, whenever you call `.on()`, you create a [back-reference](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21/lib/events.js#L146) emitter -> listener. This reference will prevent the listener from being collected by the GC and create a "leak" if you never unsubscribe.

This does not happen very often with node.js, because usually, emitters are destroyed before listeners, but a real-world case where this happens is when you have a long running connection (think Twitter Streaming API) that sometimes reconnects. If you don't unregister events, you might get events from the old connection and think they apply to the new one. This can lead you to think the new connection has closed.

node.js will print the infamous ["possible leak detected"](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21/lib/events.js#L156) message when it thinks you might be forgetting to unregister listeners.

Back to your example:

This won't create a leak because the socket (req+res) will be destroyed first. Since it's the emitter, node.js will [forcibly remove all listeners](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/f153d6da450b6ba5c78381e6e90a7ba243657691/lib/_http_server.js#L368).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot, especially for the part with when emitters get destroyed. :-)