# How to use pipe in levelup (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, stream, leveldb

LevelUP Documentation says that `pipe()` can be used (https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup/#pipes-and-node-stream-compatibility).

I've tried the following code:

```
db.createValueStream().pipe(response)
```

But I could't do it, I've got an error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:150:14)
    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:179:12)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:582:7)
    at ReadStream.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:614:5)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

The actual problem is about memory usage when a use the event 'data' (). Then i was trying do make a stream.Transform and use `pipe()` to do what a I need. Once memory leak in event emmiter is a problem: [Memory leak when using streams in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550180/memory-leak-when-using-streams-in-node-js)

UPDATE

I've tried @paul-mougel without success. The function of error event are not called, and the it crashed.
This is a piece of the code:

```
    var rs = db.createValueStream();

    request.on('close', function(){
        rs.destroy();
        response.end();
    });

    rs.on('end', function(){
        response.end();
    });
    rs.on('error', function(err){
        console.err('READ STREAM ERROR:',err.message);
        response.end();
        rs.destroy();
    });

    response.on('error', function(err){
        console.log('RESPONSE ERROR:',err);
        rs.destroy();
    });

    rs.pipe(stringifier).pipe(response);
```

Comment: You're piping a stream of objects into a stream of bytes.  The target stream can't handle objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider.

First, you get this exception because you don't listen to the `error` event. In the case of streams, always listen to it, which i) will allow you to log the issue ii) won't make the program crash.

```
var valueStream = db.createValueStream()
valueStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('valueStream.on error ' + err.message);
});
valueStream.pipe(response);
response('error', function (err) {
  console.error('response error ' + err.message);
});
```

Second, `db.createValueStream()` creates a readable stream in [object mode](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode) (see [source](https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup/blob/v0.18.1/lib/read-stream.js#L32)): it will output javascript objects. On the other hand, your `response` is a writable stream in byte mode: it only takes bytes as input, hence the `error` event. What you can do is create a [Transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) that will take javascript objects as input and output their stringified version:

```
var stream = require('stream')
var stringifier = new stream.Transform();
stringifier._writableState.objectMode = true;
stringifier._transform = function (data, encoding, done) {
    this.push(JSON.stringify(data));
    this.push('\n');
    done();
}

valueStream.pipe(stringifier).pipe(response);
```

Please note that we create a transform stream that takes objects as input and outputs bytes. See [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_state_objects) for more information.

However, you'll have to tell us more about the specific problem you're trying to solve by piping the leveled stream into a request: the above solution isn't a very good solution.

Third, you didn't encounter a memory leak when using `.on('data')`. Adding this listener transforms the stream into [flowing mode](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), which means that it will output the data as fast as possible. You could always use the `.pause()` and `.resume()` methods to stop and restart the stream. But using the new v0.10 stream interface (aka streams2) helps you to deal with this issue, as the `Readable`, `Writable` and `Transform` classes take care of all of that for you.

Comment: Sorry, I did both suggestion but it didn't work. I did not call the function in error-event function. It just crashed with the same message. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm trying to make a pipe to transform it (just like you suggested in your example) but I've got this error.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's indeed the `response` stream that emits the error, and not the `valueStream`. You should still tell us what's your goal by piping the valueStream into the HTTP response.

Comment: I'm trying to make a kind of dump o the entire base of a leveldb. But the memory usage increases a lot. I was searching a little bit about it, and I discover it was because que listener of the 'data' event, or something like that. Anyway, I tested with pipe and it worked ok, without increasing of memory. Then I tried to make the same I was doing with file stream in leveldb readstream.

Comment: Fair enough, then my Transform stream suggestion should work.

Comment: What's happening? Does it output an error? Can you share a [gist](https://gist.github.com) with some code so that we can look at it?

Comment: Paul, I'have made a code of test for reproduce the error: https://gist.github.com/leonardonsantos/7754933

Comment: Alright that was a simple mistake on my part: the Transform stream takes bytes as input and outputs objects, which means that its **writable** side is in `objectMode` and that its **readable** side is in byte mode, and not the other way around. I updated my answer and [your gist](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/7766857).