# NodeJs streaming File from request to Filesystem not Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i have an strange issue. I´m using request for file download in NodeJs and everytime i download larger files(>250mb) they get downloaded into memory and are not directly streamed to the Filesystem. Maybe i´m doing something wrong but i made a testcase and the file is still not getting streamed.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream("1GB.zip");
    var stream = request.get({
        uri: "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip",
        encoding: null
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("code:", response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode >= 500) {
            log.err(response.statusCode, " Servererror", file.url);
        }
    }).pipe(writable);
```

in this testcase i`m downloading a sample 1GB file and if you watch the node proccess with the taskmanager it grows to >1GB as it downloads the file.
I want that my Node application uses not more than 200mb of Ram

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19708936/5388620

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing a callback, which implicitly enables buffering inside `request` because one of the parameters for the callback is the entire `body` of the response.

If you want to know when the `response` is available, just listen for the `response` event instead:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var writable = fs.createWriteStream("1GB.zip");
var stream = request.get({
  uri: "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip",
  encoding: null
}).on('response', function(response) {
  console.log("code:", response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode >= 500) {
    log.err(response.statusCode, " Servererror", file.url);
  }
}).pipe(writable);
```